# Seeing JavaScript stacktrace on Error in Firefox Developer Tools (like in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, stack-trace, console.log, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way to inspect the stacktrace using the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) whenever an error occurs.

I know I can set breakpoints, but if it is an unexpected error, then the Firefox dev tools only show the place where the error occurred (usually somewhere deep in a lib like jQuery) and not the more application related stacktrace.

Something like Chrome does it:
[image]

If not yet supported, is there a bugreport for this somewhere? I search the web, but cannot find any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current Firefox (tested with Fx 44) this feature is now built in. See the toogle next to `ReferenceError`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it recently, but there's an experimental plugin to enable that: https://github.com/DavidBruant/usefulStackTrace